# Retrieving an item from a list based on selected value

Tags: vb.net, linq, list, foreach

The function retrieveFixtureReport() returns a list of Report, each of which contains a PlayerID. I'm trying to set my labels to reflect the selected Report chosen from cmbSelectedPlayer. Each Report within the list contains a unique PlayerID. I've tried a variety of different ways to access the properties of the selected Report, including LINQ, but have been unsuccessful so far. A For Each loop doesn't seem to be the right option to select just one Report, it also prevents me from selecting other PlayerID's from cmbSelectedPlayer (only the last Report in the list is shown). The code is shown below:

```
Public Sub setFixtureReport()

            'If UC_Menu_Scout1.cmbSelectedPlayer.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then

            If UC_Menu_Scout1.cmbSelectedPlayer.Items.Count > 0 Then

                Dim getPlayerReport = _
                (From rpt As Report In retrieveFixtureReport() _
                Where rpt.PlayerID = UC_Menu_Scout1.cmbSelectedPlayer.SelectedItem.PlayerID) '.AsEnumerable

                'For Each rpt As Report In getPlayerReport()

                'For Each rpt As Report In retrieveFixtureReport.Where(Function(x) x.PlayerID = UC_Menu_Scout1.cmbSelectedPlayer.SelectedItem.PlayerID)

                'Dim rpt As Report = getPlayerReport 'retrieveFixtureReport(0)

                '*****General Information
                UC_Menu_Scout1.lblRptPosition.Text = rpt.PositionPlayed
                UC_Menu_Scout1.lblFoot.Text = rpt.PreferredFoot
                UC_Menu_Scout1.txtComments.Text = rpt.Comments
                UC_Menu_Scout1.lblStatus.Text = rpt.MonitorStatus

                'Next

                setColours()
                'End If
            End If
        End Sub
```

The combobox cmbSelectedPlayer is filled from playerList (this is added to in retrieveFixxtureReport as well):

```
UC_Menu_Scout1.cmbSelectedPlayer.DataSource = playerList
        UC_Menu_Scout1.cmbSelectedPlayer.DisplayMember = "PlayerFullName"
        UC_Menu_Scout1.cmbSelectedPlayer.ValueMember = "PlayerID"
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show how to load the combobox?

Comment: I've edited the question to show how the combobox is filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your combobox was bound to a `List(Of Player)` then all you would need to do is cast the SelectedItem to it's type:

```
Dim player = TryCast(UC_Menu_Scout1.cmbSelectedPlayer.SelectedItem, Player)
If Not player Is Nothing Then
  Dim getPlayerReport = (From rpt As Report In retrieveFixtureReport()
                         Where rpt.PlayerID = player.PlayerID).FirstOrDefault()
  If Not getPlayerReport Is Nothing Then
    UC_Menu_Scout1.lblRptPosition.Text = getPlayerReport.PositionPlayed
    UC_Menu_Scout1.lblFoot.Text = getPlayerReport.PreferredFoot
    UC_Menu_Scout1.txtComments.Text = getPlayerReport.Comments
    UC_Menu_Scout1.lblStatus.Text = getPlayerReport.MonitorStatus
  End If
End If
```

Comment: I've edited the question to show how the combobox is filled. This works okay, my problem is with retrieving an individual Report, based on the PlayerID of the selected item in the combobox

Comment: What is the underlying type in this `PlayerList`?

Comment: I have another class called Player (PlayerID and PlayerFullName are used in the PlayerList), PlayerID is found in both the Player and Report classes

Comment: I attempted something similar to this beforehand, my issue was trying to declare rpt for my labels, such as: UC_Menu_Scout1.lblRptPosition.Text = rpt.PositionPlayed

Comment: You need to use the variable not the LINQ variable. Look again.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've tried your suggestion but it's emptied cmbSelectedPlayer now. I will look further into resolving this, as your answer is promising. Thanks again.

Comment: Are calling the `formname.comboboxname` instead of `Me.comboboxname`?

Comment: UC_Menu_Scout1.UcAttributes1 is my user control- the labels are found there>>> UC_Menu_Scout1.lblRptPosition.Text = getPlayerReport.PositionPlayed

Comment: Is it working? Debug it and see if the variables are finding a player and report or are they returning null/nothing?

Comment: Where is this code being called from - inside the UC or the form?

Comment: I think I have it partially working, as far as this question goes- you appear to have solved my problem. I need to add a few other things in myself to get it fully working. Thank you for your patience.